# password is in clear text within ssh

Tags: ssh, diff

I understand this is related to sshd_config below:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

What I don't understand here is my command below:

```
diff <(ssh rx52019@hostname ls -R /home/rx52019 ) <(ls -R /home/rx52019)
```

presumably it compares the two folders on two hosts recursively. The odds I am having are:

1. When I type in the password for ssh, it is showing on the terminal in clear text instead of invisible.
2. After I provided correct password, presumably it should start comparing and produce result, indeed it just hangs there.
3. I tested to run only

   ```
   ssh rx52019@hostname ls -R /home/rx52019
   ```

   it works just normal, no clear text when I type in the password, and gives me result correctly very fast.

Can anyone help me to sort it out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use key authentication if you don't want your password to be visible

Comment: You're using two input redirections. Did you test this with other, simpler input in order to confirm whenever it works?